# is it possible to do URL re-write in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have developers working on a site for me, they have told me there is no possible way to re-write the URL so there is no second level category e.g.
Remove "/category" from this URL http://www.somesite.com/category/page.aspx
I understand that page.aspx can simply go in the root folder on the server however I don't want to do this as adding heaps of pages will slow down server load time

Comment: Did the same developers tell you that adding lots of pages to the root directory will slow down server load time?

Comment: Never heard that either. Would try to find new developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not believe them... It's easy and can be done for example by [UrlRewriter.net library](http://urlrewriter.net/) which is easy to use and open source. Also they can write own rewriter which is also not more then an hour of work, for example [like here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: URL Rewite is now part of IIS7: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 2):

check whether it will helpful for your requirement: [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)